# How can I remove "Proudly powered by WordPress" from twentyeleven without modifying footer.php?

Tags: php, themes, hooks, actions, footer

How can I remove "Proudly powered by WordPress" from twentyeleven without modifying footer.php, and without creating a child theme?

I'm looking for a php command, such as `add_action`, `remove_action`, `add_filter`, or something of that sort.

I'm not looking for CSS to hide the footer.

I don't want to modify any of the theme files other than `functions.php`

Is this possible? For reference the code in the footer that is creating this is below.

```
<div id="site-generator">
    <?php do_action( 'twentyeleven_credits' ); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>"
    title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"
    rel="generator">
    <?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you not wanted to edit the footer? That's where the code is.

Comment: @cale_b - I'm sure there are in fact several ways to do this without editing the footer.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - because when the theme is upgraded it reverts back.

Comment: Got it. Makes sense. I'm starting to use Thesis and haven't seen what breaks/reverts during update, but I understand the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 methods.

1. Somewhat weird but since this text is internationalized you can filter the output. This is just an example to remove the text, the link is still present in the source.

   ```
   add_filter('gettext', 'remove_powered_by', 20, 3);

   function remove_powered_by( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {

       $custom_field_text = 'Proudly powered by %s';

       if ( !is_admin() && $untranslated_text === $custom_field_text ) {
           return '';
       }

       return $translated_text;
   }
   ```
2. Use jQuery (or javascript)

   `$('#site-generator').remove();`
3. Create a child theme and just comment out the code or delete it.

Comment: +1, but only because of option #3. I think using a Child Theme is definitely the way to go. :)